# How to fix logging and version compatibility in spark-submit of jar file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, logging, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to submit a jar file for execution on spark engine. I'm trying to integrate spark with kafka and using eclipse to build and export the jar file of the sample code https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.1.1/examples

I got two exceptions:

1) incompatiblity in versions. I'm using Scala
2.11.12, kafka_2.12-2.2.0, spark-2.4.3, java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS, spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.3 I don't
know which versions to use and which are the compatible?

2) AbstractMethodError: Receiver class
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver does not define or
inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract.

Under eclipse, I tried adding as external jars all jars in spark-2.4.3/jars.
I used the command:

> ./bin/spark-submit --files
>   /home/symlab/software/spark-2.4.3/conf/log4j.properties --conf
>   spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/symlab/software/spark-2.4.3/conf/log4j.properties'
>   --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaKafkaWordCount --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3 --master local[2] /home/symlab/software/JavaKafkaWordCount.jar localhost:2181 test-consumer-group streams-plaintext-input 1

..............................

19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver 0

```
19/06/17 18:01:06 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract initializeLogIfNecessary(ZZ)Z of interface org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1560765666000 ms
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1560765666000 ms.0 from job set of time 1560765666000 ms
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1560765666000 ms.0 from job set of time 1560765666000 ms
    19/06/17 18:01:06 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1560765666000 ms.0
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1337)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:735)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:734)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1337)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:735)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:734)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


          19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
            19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverTracker: Sent stop signal to all 1 receivers
            19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Received stop signal
            19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Stopped by driver: 
            19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
            19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
            19/06/17 18:01:06 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 

    0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract 

initializeLogIfNecessary(ZZ)Z of interface org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


19/06/17 18:01:06 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver 0
19/06/17 18:01:06 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO BlockGenerator: Stopping BlockGenerator
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage cancelled
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (start at JavaKafkaWordCount.java:93) failed in 0.649 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract initializeLogIfNecessary(ZZ)Z of interface org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:2212)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Driver stacktrace:
```

19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverTracker: All of the receivers have deregistered successfully
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker stopped
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately

...................................

19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-6728496c-68f7-427f-b0e8-11da56c6caec
19/06/17 18:01:06 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-1ca3fa84-2c38-4855-a636-f77cfd22966b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line says you are using Scala 2.11 but `kafka_2.12-...` that `_2.12` is the Scala version, get the one which says `kafka_2.11` that'd be a good start.

It's a lot easier to use sbt in my opinion, however I'll avoid being dogmatic here. Use eclipse and manual dependency manage at your own risk.

Comment: I fixed all spark and kafka versions to be compatible with scala 2.11; however I still receive exception:

 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1560825912000 ms.0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
 at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader..

Is there any conditions for compatibility with a specific java version?

Comment: When using Scala 2.11 you should be using java 8, I see you are using java 11, I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started.html

Reading documentation is boring, I know, but it should save you time in the long term.

Comment: Replacing java 11 with java 8 fixed the problem.
Thank you.